# Excel check if 2 columns have data and check for specific value in 3rd column

Tags: excel-formula

I have 3 columns in a spreadsheet and i need to do the following check:

if column1 is blank and column3 is anything except "Production" or "Pre-Production" then set TRUE else FALSE

if column1 is populated but column2 is blank and column3 is "Pre-Production" then set TRUE else FALSE

if column1 is populated and comumn2 is populated and column3 is "Production" then set TRUE else FALSE

Hopefully this makes sense, i just cant figure out the logic in excel and need assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking for a few nested `and` and `or` statements.

`=OR(AND(A1="",AND(C1<>"Production",C1<>"Pre-Production")),AND(A1<>"",OR(AND(B1="",C1="Pre-Production"),AND(B1<>"",C1="Production"))))`